# Minimal number of edits possibly too low

Tags: feature-request

I encountered a few times by now that people make formatting errors in their answers. Sometimes, they just set back ticks ("`") incorrectly, which may destroy the formatting of an entire answer or causes at least some other inconveniences, e.g. making links disappear as is the case in [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/25130/37982).

All these things are natural to happen occasionally, but the strange thing is that they cannot easily be fixed by the community since edits must alter at least 6 characters of a post to be admissible. Thus, in the case of the aforementioned post for example, I myself could not correct the formatting of the post since a correction would have involved deleting only 2 (instead of 6) "`"-signs.

Since this is not the first time that I encounter situations like this, I was wondering whether *it is possible to decrease the minimal number of characters to be changed for an edit to become admissible*.

Comment: `\`` is called a back tick

Comment: I agree with you. I haven't yet fully researched why there's this limitation, but I don't really think it's necessary. The alternative would be to try to perform other changes (which may not be necessary, though, which makes this limitation unnecessary). Check [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/287113).

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thanks, I updated the expression. @ nbro: Thanks for the reference. I see now why this is the case. Still, I don't know whether the intended benefit outweighs the "harm" of that rule. Guess I need to accumulate more reputation to get the problem fixed myself ;)